# I need to apply a Vector3 to a Vector3[] with Vector3.up, Vector3.down, ecc.but I can't

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this script and I need to assign a different value to vertices every frame but I can't convert Vector3 to Vector3[], I tried In many ways but I am not able to solve this

```
public Vector3 calculatePointOnPlanet(Vector3 directions)
{
    float firstLayerValue = 0;
    float elevation = 0;
    directions = directions;

    if (noiseFilters.Length > 0)
    {
        firstLayerValue = noiseFilters[0].Evaluate(directions);
        if (settings.noiseLayers[0].enabled)
        {
            elevation = firstLayerValue;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < noiseFilters.Length; i++)
    {
        if (settings.noiseLayers[i].enabled)
        {
            float mask = (settings.noiseLayers[i].useFirstLayerAsMask) ? firstLayerValue : 1;
            elevation += noiseFilters[i].Evaluate(directions) * mask;
        }
    }
    return directions * settings.radius * (1 + elevation);
}
public void a(Vector3[] vertices, Vector3[] directions)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < noiseFilters.Length; i++)
    {
        
        vertices[i] = calculatePointOnPlanet(directions);
    }
}
```

Comment: `new[]{directions}`

Comment: where I need to put it?

Comment: its not clear what you want to do. Set the components of the vector3? Use .x .y and .z. Vector3[] is an array of vector3, there is no point in converting a Vector3 in an array of vectors

Comment: You didn't post any errors or show where the error occurs. You asked how to convert a single item to an array of items: you create a new array with that item.

Comment: Nothing I solved but thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably forgot the index

```
//                                              | 
//                                              V
vertices[i] = calculatePointOnPlanet(directions[i]);
```

Note btw that

```
directions = directions
```

does absolutely nothing